# XML-less @Configuration (no persistence.xml) and openjpa-maven-plugin

Tags: java, spring, maven, openjpa, openjpa-maven-plugin

Trying to convert my app (spring + jpa) to spring's annotation based @Configuration and get rid of spring app context xml and persistence.xml. All good except openjpa-maven-plugin 2.2.2 i use for build time class enhancement won't work without persistence.xml throwing the error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.openjpa:openjpa-maven-plugin:2.2.2:enhance (enhancer) on
>   project myapp: Execution enhancer of goal
>   org.apache.openjpa:openjpa-maven-plugin:2.2.2:enhance failed:
>   MetaDataFactory could not be configured
>   (conf.newMetaDataFactoryInstance() returned null). This might mean
>   that no configuration properties were found. Ensure that you have a
>   META-INF/persistence.xml file, that it is available in your classpath,
>   or that the properties file you are using for configuration is
>   available. If you are using Ant, please see the  or
>    attributes of the task's nested  element.
>   This can also occur if your OpenJPA distribution jars are corrupt, or
>   if your security policy is overly strict.

plugin's configuration is:

```
      <configuration>
           <includes>**/business/model/*.class</includes>
           <addDefaultConstructor>true</addDefaultConstructor>
           <enforcePropertyRestrictions>true</enforcePropertyRestrictions>
      </configuration>
```

It works, however, with persistence.xml existing but containing nothing but empty persistence units (i have 3 of them):

```
<persistence-unit name="pu1" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
</persistence-unit>

<persistence-unit name="pu2" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
</persistence-unit>

<persistence-unit name="pu3" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
</persistence-unit>
```

So the only information openjpa-maven-plugin may possibly get from this is persistence-unit names, if it even actually needs them.

Any way to implement build time openjpa class enhancement without persistence.xml?